# What type of switch is this?

Tags: switches

I need switch which is normally closed, but when I press it, it goes to off state. As soon as I move finger from it, it must go to default state (normally closed). Which type of switch is this? I need two of them, for limit switch control of DC motor when it reaches full travel in either direction.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I have a feeling that you need a normally closed limit switch!

Comment: Normally closed momentary action push switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a limit switch (often called "Microswitch") - this type of switch is designed to be controlled by things, rather than directly by a person.  Most such switches are single pole, double throw (SPDT), so they can be used as either normally open or normally closed.

Limit switches are available as pushbuttons, or with various lever or roller actuator arms.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer. I found this http://www.ebay.com/itm/5-Red-Hole-16mm-2-Pin-SPST-ON-OFF-3A-125VAC-NC-Momentary-Push-Button-Switch-/271202014904?hash=item3f24e656b8:g:-sUAAOxydkZRkdfQ  That's it?

Comment: The button in your ebay link is Normally Closed, and would probably work for you, but is intended to be pushed by a finger.  The ones shown in Spehro's anwer are what I was thinking of, and what would normally be used for a limit switch.

Comment: There is mechanism which will push switch when motor reach full travel. I saw Spehro's answer but I'm not sure what is current rating of these limit switches

Answer (score 2):

I was just ordering some of these for a CNC setup. Here's (a few of) [Omron's offerings](https://components.omron.com/components/web/pdflib.nsf/0/426FBC003DD57FE185257201007DD495/$file/SS-P_1110.pdf). They are quite cheap. 
[image]

Fancier ones have a roller at the end of the lever, but the curved "simulated roller" is good enough for many applications (and might be a bit more repeatable if that matters- which it doesn't typically for a limit switch).

[image]

They are SPDT so they have both a N.O. and a N.C. contact, just ignore the one you don't need.

For more space-constrained applications, there are many, many types of tiny SMT limit and detector switches used in things like optical drives- though most are normally open. Here is a photo of one (credit to [Digikey](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/SDS005R/CKN10233CT-ND/2218823)):

[image]

This one is only about 5mm square, not counting the plunger.